# 'Module' Object is not collable

Tags: python, neural-network

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9TbT.jpg)I am trying to run this part of the code and I am getting the TypeError

```
data_dir = '../Cat_Dog_data/train'

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                            transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir, transform = transforms)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size = 32, shuffle = True)

# Run this to test your data loader
images, labels = next(iter(dataloader))
helper.imshow(images[0], normalize=False)
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d9e81831faed> in <module>()
      1 # Run this to test your data loader
----> 2 images, labels = next(iter(dataloader))
      3 helper.imshow(images[0], normalize=False)
.
.
.
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is *helper*?

Comment: Have you redefined `next` or `iter`?

Comment: No I did not redefine them.

Comment: Please post the _full_ error message

Comment: `print(next,iter)` (or log) right before that line - result?

Comment: I added a picture to make it clear